# Is it legal to hand over fake money during a robbery?

Tags: currency

I am wondering whether it is legal to hand over fake money during a robbery or another crime. For instance handing over fake money as payment for a kidnapping or blackmail.

Comment: @Robert Columbia
That refers to actual counterfeit money.f by "fake money" is meant something like Monopoly money or something else that is not legally a counterfeit, then the issues are different. If not it is a duplicate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fake money"? Counterfeit money? or play money?